# AngularJS, Fabric.js ngRepeat:dupes

Tags: javascript, angularjs, canvas, fabricjs

Can not resolve this problem. I am trying to apply some presets to my canvas element. The definitions in my controller are like this:

```
//  Add some Preset sizes for the canvas

$scope.presetSizes = [{
        id: 1,
        name: 'iPad Landscape',
        height: 768,
        width: 1024
    },
    {
        id: 2,
        name: 'iPad Portrait',
        height: 1024,
        width: 766
    },
    {
        id: 3,
        name: 'iPad Pro Landscape',
        height: 1024,
        width: 1366
    },
    {

        id: 4,
        name: 'iPad Pro Portrait',
        height: 1366,
        width: 1024
    }
  ];
```

And this is my function:

```
$rootScope.getCanvasPreset = function(width, height) {

    canvas.fabric.setHeight(height);
    canvas.fabric.setWidth(width);
    canvas.original.width = width;
    canvas.original.height = height;

    var objects = canvas.fabric.getObjects();
    for (var i in objects) {
        var scaleX = objects[i].scaleX;
        var scaleY = objects[i].scaleY;
        var left = objects[i].left;
        var top = objects[i].top;

        var tempScaleX = scaleX * widthScale;
        var tempScaleY = scaleY * heightScale;
        var tempLeft = left * widthScale;
        var tempTop = top * heightScale;

        objects[i].scaleX = tempScaleX;
        objects[i].scaleY = tempScaleY;
        objects[i].left = tempLeft;
        objects[i].top = tempTop;

        objects[i].setCoords();
    }

    canvas.fabric.renderAll();
};
```

Finally in my controll panel I am using this md-select control:

```
<div class="clearfix">
    <md-select ng-model="presetSizes" ng-change="getCanvasPreset(size.width, size.height)" placeholder="Select a size preset">
        <md-option ng-repeat='size in presetSizes track by $index'>{{ size.name }}</md-option>
    </md-select>
</div>
```

No matter what I am doing, I am getting a duplicate error. I thought that "track by $Index" would resolve this, but no chance...

Comment: Try changing to simple quotes ( ' ) to double quotes ( " ) in the template, what happens then?

Comment: You mean in the presetSizes for example 'iPad Landscape' to "iPad Landscape"? Tried this but in fact I am getting the same errors: Error: Duplicate md-option values are not allowed in a select. Duplicate value "" found.
    at SelectMenuController.self.addOption (scripts.min.js?v28:15651)
    at Object.setOptionValue [as fn] (scripts.min.js?v28:15770)
    at l.$digest (scripts.min.js?v28:3289)
    at l.$apply (scripts.min.js?v28:3291)
    at HTMLElement.clickListener (scripts.min.js?v28:15516)
    at HTMLElement.dispatch (jquery.js:3)
    at HTMLElement.r.handle (jquery.js:3)

Comment: No, I mean in the template: `ng-repeat='size in presetSizes track by $index'` use double quotes like this: `ng-repeat="size in presetSizes track by $index"`

Comment: @GMaiolo – btw. track by $Index is funnily breaking everything if applyed to my code below...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First of all you have to change the ngRepeat to use double quotes, after that you will be able to track by $index, but you should track by the internal object's id whenever's possible.

Would end up with something like this:

```
ng-repeat="size in presetSizes track by size.id"
```

Answer (score 0):

Problem (almost) solved. This made now almost my day:

```
<md-input-container>
    <md-select ng-model="presetSizes" placeholder="Select a Preset" style="width: 280px; margin-left:10px;">
        <md-option ng-click="getCanvasPreset(size.width, size.height)" ng-repeat="size in presetSizes">{{ size.name }}</md-option>
    </md-select>
</md-input-container>
```

@GMaiolo At least my function is working now. But I am getting this errors while I choose an option:

```
Error: [ngRepeat:dupes] http://errors.angularjs.org/1.3.9/ngRepeat/dupes?p0=size%20in%20presetSizes&p1=string%3AP&p2=P
```

Comment: Just posted a full answer